# Insert text to active cell from button click based on drop-down list [Excel]

Tags: excel, vba, button, excel-formula

I'm an excel newbie and am trying to design a worksheet to insert text in an active cell based on options selected from a drop-down list for different types of foods.

As in the pseudo-code, when the button is clicked, how do I insert a text in the active cell corresponding to the conditions (i.e. different texts for different conditions of Language/Food) and that which contains/concatenates the inputs from the drop-down lists?

I was able to create drop-down lists for each of the inputs (Progress attached in images) and wrote down a pseudo-code for the result expected but unfortunately, I have no idea how to proceed further with regards to configuring the button.

**Pseudo-Code:**

```
//Drop-down list to select Language and Food
Select Language:<English, Spanish: From drop-down list>
Select Food:<Fruits, Vegetables, Spices, Pulses: From drop-down list>

//Drop-down list to select type, color and country of origin of food
1. Select Type:<From drop-down list>
2. Select Color:<From drop-down list>
3. Select Country of origin:<From drop-down list>

//Configure a button to insert text in an active cell of the worksheet when clicked
If(Button Pressed)
{
 If (Language Selected: English)
  {
   If (Food Selected: Fruits)
    {
     Insert Text 1 in active cell ("Lorem ipsum <Type option from drop-down
     list 1> dolor sit amet, consectetur <Color option from drop-down list 2> 
    adipiscing elit. Donec mollis <Origin option from drop-down list> felis nisi, nec sodales")
    }
   If (Food Selected: Vegetables)
    {
      Insert Text 2 in active cell ("The <Type option from drop-down list 1> is one 
    of the most popular vegetables in the world. It is usually <Color option from drop-down list 2> in color 
and originates from <Origin option from drop-down list>")
    }
   }
 else
  {
   If (Food Selected: Fruits)
    {
      Insert Text 3 in active cell ("Spanish Text:Hola! <Type option from drop-down
 list 1> Me llamo Pedro y hoy quiero hablar del parque que hay <Color option from drop-down list 2> junto a mi casa. Yo me divierto todos <Origin option from drop-down list>")
    }
   If (Food Selected: Spices)
    {
      Insert Text 4 in active cell ("Hola,<Type option from drop-down
 list 1> is one of the most popular spices in the world. It is usually <Color option from drop-down list 2> 
in color and originates from <Origin option from drop-down list>")
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

**Images:**

Drop-down List:

[image: Drop-Down-List]

TestCase: Button+Drop-Down-List

[image: TestCase: Button+Drop-Down-List]

**Update:**

Based on the input from Tim, I am now able to conditionally check and insert the text in an active cell. Below a snapshot from the working code.

[image: Working Code]

Comment: It's just concatenating text from 4 cells into your template - `Range("A20").Value = "Hello - you chose a " & Range("B5") & " named " & Range("B9").Value & " which is " ..... `

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim! The concatenation does indeed take in the values from the 4 cells but it is not conditionally selected. How would I insert a different text for the conditions of Language and Food as in the pseudo-code? I have also edited the post to further refine the question

Comment: You can use If-Then blocks as your pseudocode uses, only use VBA syntax...  Have you tried that?

Comment: Works perfectly with the conditional blocks! Have attached an image of the code, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Maybe as a font feature, is it possible to have this inserted concatenated text in bold as in the test case?

Comment: You'd need to use the cell's `Characters` property to apply the bold format once the cell has been populated.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Tim!